# Generate .rds files below 100MB to avoid Git LFS

Tags: r, github, chunking

I have a bunch of fit.objects which produce *.rds files larger than 100MB. GitHub comes with a file size limitation of 100MB and the solution of git lfs doesn't fit me since I don't want to pay for their services.

*Background & possible solutions*
This question is a result of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71512496/partition-a-large-list-into-chunks-with-convenient-i-o/71516927?noredirect=1#comment126403959_71516927). A solution for data.frames is proposed but not all fit.objects can be easily transformed into data.frame objects. See [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71560268/tidy-function-cant-process-last-fit-obejcts)

**Question : What is the best solution to commit large `*.rds` files via GitHub without using git lfs?**

Comment: I think this needs to be broken into two questions. As for the second,, I personally don't tend to think of git repos as a great place to store 100+MB data files. Granted, I think they support large *artifacts* (releases), can't be sure. Perhaps you can automate (via github actions or similar) the production of these large files?

Comment: Alright I will split the question and link the question of the broom error in this one to help a possible path for a solution!
What do you mean by "production of these large files"? Any kind of script which splits large files with 100MB max filesize?

Comment: My comment is based solely on my experience with GH repos: I've only seen large-ish files in a repos "Releases" section. I don't know if the GH filesize restrictions apply to releases, I'm just suggesting that as a path of research if you had not already considered it. (I'm not a GH guru, it's just a thought.) Good luck!

Comment: You can use https://dvc.org/ for versioning data. Files be hosted somewhere else (network storage, S3, ...)

Comment: I don't know what sort of "fit.objects" you are talking about, but many fitted models contains copies of all the data and a lot of other stuff that you might not need to save, depending on your use case. [See this blog entry that drastically reduces the size of a GLM fitted model](https://win-vector.com/2014/05/30/trimming-the-fat-from-glm-models-in-r/).

Comment: But I would also strongly reinforce the other comments that suggest that Github isn't an appropriate place to store large files in general. DVC looks cool, but a relatively simple solution is to create an S3 bucket and just stick your models there, include a timestamp or version number in the file name if you need to track version.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I guess I will follow this advice. Can anyone recommend any free S3 which is not Google?